# How to read the messages having timestamp greater than the given timestamp from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I see lot of answers on using the offsetsForTimes. Can't I just read the messages that have timestamp greater than the given timestamp, rather than going for offsetsForTimes. Something like below

```
            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            if (record.timestamp() > startTimestamp) {
```

//process only these records

Why do I need to use the offsetsForTimes?

Answer (score 0):

You can. But there is an index in Kafka based on timestamps, so you can easily position the consumer to the first message, which has timestamp greater than specified.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is resources usage in the consumer and the server: processing all the records in a topic may require a lot of  CPU, network and memory than processing just what you need.